# Цикл в цикле while

Tags: php

Как сделать цикл while в цикле while. Когда дочерний цикл проходит, он останавливает родительский, а как сделать чтобы все циклы продолжали идти?

Циклы перебирают результат запроса.

```
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {

     какие то действия

          while($rowg = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {

          ещё какие то действия

          }

    }
```

Вот так не работает.

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не может такого быть.

1. У вас точно нету пересечения циклов?
2. Параметры никак не связаны между собой?

P.S. в крайнем случае можно вынести один из циклов в отдельную функцию, которую запускать из первого.
P.P.S. попробуйте создать дубликат **$result** и использовать разные курсоры.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_1) ) {

 какие то действия

      while($rowg = mysql_fetch_array($result_2) ) {

      ещё какие то действия

      }

}
```

P.P.P.S. ещё вариант использовать **`mysql_result()`** вместо **`mysql_fetch_array()`** и перебирать уже номер строки запроса. Только проблема будет с количеством строк. Расписал этот вариант:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
     die('Неверный запрос: '.mysql_error());
}
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($i=0;$i++;%i<$num_rows){
$row = mysql_result($result,$i);
какие то действия;

   for($j=0;$j++;%j<$num_rows){
   $rowg = mysql_result($result,$j);
   ещё какие то действия;
   }

}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Ещё один вариант **предложенный в комментариях** (*через массив*):

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
     die('Неверный запрос: '.mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$arr[] = $row;
}
$num_rows = count($arr);

for($i=0;$i++;%i<$num_rows){
$row = $arr[$i];
какие то действия;

   for($j=0;$j++;%j<$num_rows){
   $rowg = $arr[$j];
   ещё какие то действия;
   }

}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Поправка. Циклы перебирают результат запроса. while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { тут ещё такой цикл };

Comment: Дополнил ответ...

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: Теперь-то почему? о_О Не может такого быть... Они друг от друга теперь не зависят... Вы точно сделали что-то вроде:  

    $result_1 = mysql_query($query);
    $result_2 = mysql_query($query);

Comment: Заработало. я просто приравнял переменные к одному запросу и всё. Но 3 одинаковых запроса в бд, как то не очень. Есть ли более лучшее решение? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А зачем, если не секрет вам такая конструкция? :) Если запрос один(одинаковый), нельзя ли сделать все действия одним циклом?
Ещё вариант на уровне **SQL** а не **PHP** используя курсоры. Но вариант будет громоздкий и трудный для понимания.

Comment: А шо, массивы таки закончились?

Comment: Array()!!! И вообще напишите саму задачу целиком, может есть иное решение, ибо если Вы делаете такую конструкцию в коде, то структура таблицы не очень-то и оптимальная...

Comment: Дописал код, раз не понимаете словами) принимайте вариант)

Comment: Интересно сколько памяти займет такой массив если у тебя таблица с тысячами строк. А если еще и сайт станет популярным, хотя бы десяток обращений в секунду. Лучше исключить такой большой массив. Делай прямые обращения на строку в БД - $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$i'"

Comment: можно еще указатель передвигать (запоминать перед вложенным массивом указатель внешнего цикла, выставлять указатель в 0, проходить вложенный цикл, восстанавливать указатель)

Answer (score 3):

Родительский цикл прерывается, потому что дочерний цикл перебирает полностью результат запроса и не оставляет ничего родительскому. Посему он и прерывается, точнее заканчивает свою работу корректно, обработав всего лишь первую запись из результата, а последующие записи запроса обрабатывает дочерний цикл. А то, что Вы присваиваете результат запроса разным переменным, ничего не меняет, `mysql_fetch_array($result)` все равно сдвигает на шаг вперед "курсор".

Чтобы решить проблему, Вам нужно иметь разные ссылки на разные запросы.

Answer (score 1):

Хотите сказать, что такая конструкция не работает?

```
while($i<$b){
//код
while($c<$h){
//код
}
//код
}
//код
```

Comment: Так будет работать, но у меня чуть другое (исправил вопрос).

Answer (score 0):

А, так у вас ряды запроса, может, заканчиваются. Там же при fetch'е указатель сдвигается.

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях выкладывается весь код.

Если у тебя  и в дочернем и родительском цикле $result имеет одинаковое значение(т.е. ссылается на одну и ту же таблицу) то конечно работать не будет. Она тебе проштудирует всю таблицу до конца, и остановится, сколько бы родительских циклов у тебя не было. В таком случае $result_1 и $result_2 тоже не помогут, так как сама база данных говорит что таблица закончилась.

Выход:

Посчитать количество строк в таблице, занести значение в переменную ($tab) и оперировать уже прямыми ссылками на строки. Тут лаконичнее использовать циклы for:

```
for($i=0;$i++;%i<$tab){

   ...

   for($j=0;$j++;%j<$tab){

   ...

   }

}
```

Comment: посчитать количество строк этой функцией mysql_num_rows? А с прямыми ссылками на строку не понял.

Comment: Спасибо. Понял, завтра попробую.

Comment: Артём, последним вариантом(_P.P.P.S._) я это же и написал. Правда не так подробно.

Comment: в том смысл форумов, доходчиво и понятно, и как можно более подробно объяснять(либо сбросить ссылку где уже подробно расписано) так как человек задающий этот вопрос по определению мало чего в этой области знает.

Comment: Дописал код, раз люди не понимают словами)

Comment: Прямая ссылка как делаю я (может есть что то иное)
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$i'"; //текст обращение к БД
$result=@mysql_query($sql,$conn); //само обращние
$user = mysql_fetch_array($result); // сохранение строки таблицы в массив.
каждую таблицу я снабжаю столбцом id, текст обращения к БД ищет нужное значение id равное $i (или $j) в таблице. В итоге $users у меня массив который я могу использовать как надо на данный момент цикла ($users['id'], $users['name'], $users['password']).

Answer (score 0):

Используй функцию ресет:  [reset](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.reset.php).

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   ...
   reset($sub_result);
   while ($subrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sub_result)) {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```